# setTag() for Marker doesnt work for me in Android

Tags: android

```
    mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(SYDNEY)
            .title("Sydney"));
      mSydney.setTag(0);
```

I have that piece of code (very simple) but Android studio complains that cannot resolve method setTag('int'), i tried putting there a custom object but still cannot recognize.

Comment: Can you try Going to Build > Clean Project

Comment: i did it, no success, when i say mSydney. and see the options I dont have setTag, but I have for example setTitle.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to update your GoogleMaps library version. To my knowledge the setTag() method came after version 9.4.0; the current version is 9.6.1 if you want to just make the jump to that.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
```